# Spring Boot : Route request between two services

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, routes

I'm writing a service using Spring Boot. I have service C which act as routing between two service A and B.

How can I route requests between two services?

In application.properties file of service C I have defined the follwing ports:

```
#port on which service c runs
server.port=8084 

#port on which service a runs
service.a.host=localhost:8086

#port on which service b runs
service.b.host=localhost:8082
```

What is the best practice to do the same? Defining the ports in application.properties is that the only thing I need to do?

Comment: why not use spring-cloud-zuul? although we commonly use it as api gateway to outside. but i think you can use its router tech to resolve your requirement.

Comment: Okay, Thank you for your time and response.